# What does sys_vm86old syscall do?

Tags: system-calls

My question is quite simple.

I encountered this `sys_vm86old` syscall (when reverse engineering) and I am trying to understand what it does.

I found two sources that could give me something but I'm still not sure that I fully understand; these sources are
The [Source Code](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/x86/kernel/vm86_32.c?v=3.3#L201) and this [page](https://xorl.wordpress.com/2010/11/20/grkernsec_vm86-restrict-vm86-mode/) which gives me this paragraph (but it's more readable directly on the link):

> config GRKERNSEC_VM86
>   bool "Restrict VM86 mode"
>     depends on X86_32
>
> help:
>       If you say Y here, only processes with CAP_SYS_RAWIO will be able to
>       make use of a special execution mode on 32bit x86 processors called
>       Virtual 8086 (VM86) mode.  XFree86 may need vm86 mode for certain
>       video cards and will still work with this option enabled.  The purpose
>       of the option is to prevent exploitation of emulation errors in
>       virtualization of vm86 mode like the one discovered in VMWare in 2009.
>       Nearly all users should be able to enable this option.

From what I understood, it would ensure that the calling process has cap_sys_rawio enabled. But this doesn't help me a lot...

Can anybody tell me ?
Thank you

Comment: Virtual Machine x86 old computer?

Answer (score 2):

The syscall is used to execute code in VM86 mode. This mode allows you to run old "real mode" 32bit code (like present in some BIOS) inside a protected mode OS.

See for example the Wikipedia article on it: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_8086_mode

The setting you found means you need CAP_SYS_RAWIO to invoke the syscall.

I think X11 especially is using it to call BIOS methods for switching the video mode. There are two syscalls, the one with old suffix offers less operations but is retained for binary (ABI) compatibility.